# Вызов Google App Script из PHP

Tags: php, google-apps-script

Код вызова скрипта выглядит следующим образом

```
<?php

include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents");

$client->setAccessToken(require('TOKEN.php'));

try {
    $script = new Google_Service_Script($client);

    $scriptBody = new Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
    $scriptBody->setFunction('myFunction');
    //$scriptBody->setParameters([]);
    $scriptBody->setDevMode(true);

    //DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()
    $result = $script->scripts->run('177Vt54Z-diSzUqV9TWEXcAlPAHcPYkhBRSmGEtsza60', $scriptBody);

    //Project key
    //$result = $script->scripts->run('Mvdxvn6AxcoJR2H1wIsro6gRkjHxb-ANQ', $scriptBody);

    //SDC key
    //$result = $script->scripts->run('b553ab21c0abcc1f', $scriptBody);

    //Script ID
    //$result = $script->scripts->run('1i-Z0JC-VzfPNcUW10kZro-DgzaNUsesAbY4a95LWjKa1vG2_kcYSAG_g', $scriptBody);


    return $result;
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Ловлю ошибку такого формата. В документации ничего не нашел. Чтоб бы это могло быть?

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "code":400,
      "message":"Request contains an invalid argument.",
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "message":"Request contains an invalid argument.",
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"badRequest"
         }
      ],
      "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"
   }
}
```

Скрипт рабочий, если запустить ручками, то тестовый файл создается

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.create('TEST');
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  DriveApp
    .getFolderById('0B4tpfK4Y0ag7RF9reUtRVkhYNkU')
    .addFile(docFile);
}
```

Кто-то может поделится рабочим примером вызова скрипта из сервера?

Также смущает что ScriptId если взять из 
**File** -> **Project Properties**, как советуют в документации то возвращает

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "code":404,
      "message":"Requested entity was not found.",
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "message":"Requested entity was not found.",
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"notFound"
         }
      ],
      "status":"NOT_FOUND"
   }
}
```

Поэтому ID брал из самого скрипта

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()
```

Comment: У вас встроенный в Документ скрипт?

Comment: Нет. Отдельным скриптом. Вопрос уже отпал)

Comment: Добавьте решение в ответ и отметьте его как лучший